# Loop "while" is not satisfying both conditions with interrupt

Tags: c, loops, interrupt, avr, stm32

I'm waiting some time for a real-world event (e.g. push a button for 3 seconds) on an AVR or STM32 MCU, and I have trouble with code like:

```
#define PRESS_BUTTON
int waiting = 0;
int t_ms = 0; // time counter
//...

int main(void)
{           
    while(1)
    {           
        waiting = t_ms + 3000; // waiting button 3 sec

        while ((t_ms < waiting) && (!PRESS_BUTTON)) // infinite loop
        {}                  
        printf("out"); // not printed
        waiting = t_ms = 0;
    }    
}

ISR( TIMER0_OVF_vect ) // timer interrupt
{
    t_ms++;
}
```

But if I add a `printf()` inside the `while` loop, it works!

The same thing happens if I use a `do...while` loop either. What is causing this?

Comment: The power of `volatile` keyword. Change to `volatile int t_ms = 0;`

Comment: In addition to adding `volatile`, how do you de-bounce the button? This needs to be done in either software or hardware, otherwise the program will always behave poorly.

Comment: Only once every 5 full moons do I see the `volatile` properly needed on stackoverflow. Good question.

Comment: It *could* be the missing `volatile`, but could also be the missing `'\n'` in the `printf` that could well use a buffer flush to actually print something. "It works when I add a `printf`" hints to that.

Comment: Thanks! 
@Lundin Usually for de-bounce the button I use just a small delay and repeat a survey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare t_ms with volatile

```
volatile int t_ms =0;
```

Volatile tells the compiler that the variable may be changed due to external factors, and because of this the compiler will never assume it will stay the same.

In other words, it will force the compiler to check every loop to see if t_ms has changed instead of assuming it will never change.

Comment: Be careful in assuming atomicity though, generally-speaking this is unsafe for any non-`sig_atomic_t` types. In particular the 8-bit AVR architecture in question here ebds up reading the low and high bytes separately and may therefore see a torn value in case of an interrupt race. The easiest workaround, beyond masking interrupts, is to read the MSB, LSB and MSB parts in sequence and spin if the second read is a mismatch (though beyond monotonically increasing counters this strategy may run into ABA problems.)